# How does this particular operational amplifier as a comparator work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

The op-amp is super weird and not similar to any other op-amps I have seen.

I don't understand how R2 is connected to the 12 V instead of the V out, or where the voltage is coming from, if the sensor is providing voltage.

[image]

Comment: R2 would be connected to Vout if this were a linear amplifier circuit, but it is not.  It is a comparator circuit, and a comparator is not a linear amplifier so those configurations do not apply here.  Also, this is a concept drawing, not a full-fledged schematic.  There are no component values, power supply decoupling, fan driver, etc.

Answer (score 2):

That is probably intended to be a comparator, not an op-amp.

R1 and R2 form a voltage divider to provide a reference voltage (400 mV) to the comparator negative input.

If the voltage from the unknown sensor is above 400 mV, the comparator output will go High - whether that turns the fan off or on depends on how the fan is connected.

There may be more information on the intended operation wherever you found the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it is indeed supposed to be a comparator. The circuit is intended to turn when the sensor detects a temperature of 40 degrees celsius which corresponds to the 400 mV. 2 things I dont understand are why R2 is connected directly to the 12V input to the fan. The other doubt I have is within the voltage divider no values are given for R1 and R2 but a value of 1KN is assumed for R1, and just wanted to know why.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The positive end of the R1/R2 voltage divider is the +12 V supply.  If R1 is 1K Ohm (1000 Ohms), then R2 should be 29 K Ohms.

Comment: I get that, but why is the 1K ohm assumed, and why is R2 directly connected to 12v instead of v out, like it usually is

Comment: If the top of R2 was connected to the op-amp output, the voltage at the negative input would not be a stable 400 mV - it would vary with the op-amp output voltage.  You are thinking of R2 being the feedback resistor in an amplifier.  You would have to ask the designer why R1 is 1K - it could be any of a wide range of values, with R2 adjusted to keep the R1/R2 junction at 400 mV.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me more than you can imagine